# Do views get shared between all servers in a Couchbase cluster?

Tags: couchbase

I have a production server and a locally ran server (Couchbase).
I have some views on the development side of the production server I need to sync with my local server.

Do all the views get sync'd across the Cluster? (development views and/or production views?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views get synchronised across all nodes in a cluster.

If you have two independent clusters then you'll need to duplicate your design documents on both clusters. This is the case even if you are using XDCR to synchronise the bucket contents between clusters.